# How can I change text color of a product dropdown in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, textcolor

I am currently trying to change the text color of product variation drop down menu.  Currently, when I use the drop down menu, the font shows up light gray on a white background and is hard to read.  [enter See snippet from site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ5lq.png)In addition, I want to change the font color for "Description" and "additional information".  I am using wordpress and Catch Responsive theme.

Answer (score 0):

While the actual CSS of the site would be nice to have, the main `woocommerce.css` file has the following selector:

```
.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li.active a
```

So, either in your child theme file or your **Appearance** > **Customizer** > **Additional CSS** you can add:

```
.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li.active a {
    color: #333; /* Pick Color Here */
}
```

Inactive tabs have the selector: `.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a`

While those selectors are relatively overcomplicated, they're in the base CSS so you'll need a selector at least as specific to get them to work.